# convert html to powerpoint

Tags: c#, html, powerpoint-2013

I am trying to find a way to convert HTML page to a Powerpoint file (.ppt/.pptx) using C# but mostly that I found is another way around (Powerpoint to HTML). I've heard of using OpenXML for this but I cannot found a good example for it and I have never use OpenXML before. Need some guidance on this

Comment: The question in current for is way too broad for SO. You may try to narrow down you problem to particular HTML structure... Also your post may be interpreted as "please find me tutorial on OpenXML" which would be off-topic as "search for sites/books/tutorials".

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm not exactly focusing OpenXML actually. Any library would be fine. I did some Googling before asking here and mostly that I found is parsing HTML to PDF, DOCs, IMAGE but hardly found for parsing HTML to Powerpoint. Just asking here if anyone have actually done it before.

Comment: Alright to be specific. Let's say parsing a HTML table instead of the whole page to Powerpoint.